# SVM Primal Optimization and Dual Optimization. Under what cases one better than another?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

Primal $$argmin_{w} \frac{1}{2}||w||^2 + \frac{1}{N}\sum max(1-t^{(i)}(w^Tx+b),0)$$.

The dual form

$$max_{\alpha} \sum\alpha_i - \frac{1}{2}\sum t^{(i)}  t^{(j)}\alpha_i\alpha_j K(x^{(i)},x^{(j)})$$

By optimizing dual form, we have $w = \sum\alpha_it^{(i)}x^{(i)}$ such that $\forall i, \alpha_i(1-(w^Tx^{(i)} + b)) = 0$. Where, there only a subset of vectors satisfies the constraint. Optimizing Dual form clearly has advatanges in term of efficiency since we only need to compute the subset of vectors. While, optimizing primal requires the computation of the whole data set.

However, is there any cases that we prefer to optimizing prime instead of dual?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. If you solve the dual of the primal, you are solving the same problem. So apart from efficiency, why would any other factor play a role here in deciding whether to optimize the primal or dual?

Comment: @JeremiasK. thanks for reply; it's review questions when I'm study for the exam. The question asks that when would you optimize primal SVM and when would you optimize dual SVM and Why. I'm confused that it looks to me that solving prime gives no advantages while solving dual is computational efficient. I don't see the point of the question from my review sheet of asking "when would you optimize primal"

Comment: [Is Primal Better than Dual](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-04274-4_88). Hope it helps.